# I want to use data only for spark then which file format is best for hive?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I want to access table only for spark then in which format i should store table data in hive ? (orc or parquet or avro or csv or text or sequence) ?? why ??

I am not going to use this table any where , i just use for spark ony.

Comment: Very broad, volumes?

Comment: Very broad, purpose? Reporting, analytics, random access?

Comment: For analytics purpose

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is not closed yet I will try to answer and provide some argument.

1. Since Spark 2.3 native ORC support was added and many issues with ORC were fixed, such as vectorized reading and writing, predicate push-down, schema evolution, index and Bloom filter usage and many other improvements and fixes. Before Spark 2.3 better use Parquet, it works much faster and free of many issues. Also according to Hortonworks presentation some complex types cannot be used in ORC with native support, also ORC native ACID support is work in progress. If these limitations are critical then use Parquet.
2. ORC is much better supported in Hive on MR and Tez since the very beginning: Vectorizing, PPD and ACID will work with ORC fine in Hive. You said it will be used only in Spark, but who knows who will also query your tables and why you mentioned Hive in the question. Analytics/BI software may use Hive, not Spark.
3. Sequence format, textfile and avro which you also mentioned cannot even be compared with ORC and Parquet due to lack of many features such as PPD, Vectorizing and ACID. Sequence is a splittable container, which you do not need with Parquet or ORC, these are splittable also.

Check this Hortonworks presentation: [orc-improvement-in-apache-spark-2-3](https://dataworkssummit.com/berlin-2018/session/orc-improvement-in-apache-spark-2-3/) - it contains improvements details, comparison with Parquet, benchmark tests and some limitations details.

Comment: As you can see far too broad.